# Can a 'using' be made in a class independent of the class' template?

Tags: c++, templates, using

If I use a `typedef` or `using` inside a class or struct, I sometimes want it to be independent of the templates used for that class or struct.

In the example below, I would use `Object<T>::RefCountT`, which would work, but I would rather use something like `Object::RefCountT` in this case, because then I don't have to arbitrarily pick a type (which may be confusing when read).

```
template <typename T>
struct Object {
    using RefCountT = unsigned short; // This is independent of T
};
```

To me, the obvious (but not ideal) solution would be to just define it outside of the class, like

```
using ObjectRefCountT = unsigned short;
```

I also attempted to make a redefinition with no templates, assuming that they would not be considered the same, but this caused the expected error about redefinition.

I'm assuming that since it's a class not a function, I can't do it implicitly and how would the compiler know that it doesn't matter here?

Comment: Perhaps something like `using ObjectBlank = Object<void*>`

Comment: can you clarify where you would use `Object::RefCountT` ? If the `RefCountT` alias should be independent of `Object` then maybe it shouldnt be a member

Comment: I don't want to say that it is `unsigned short` since it may change in the future, but other methods and functions that aren't part of this have functions which accept or return Object's reference count so I need to use the type `Object<T>:RefCountT`.

Comment: As described, what you want isn't possible, since `Object` is not the name of a class - `Object<T>` is (for any `T` for which the template is instantiated).   If the template for `Object` is in a namespace (or a class) then place your typedef in the enclosing namespace/class, but outside the template for `Object`.     Then the type can be used as `EnclosingNamespace::RefCountT`

Comment: I just wonder where you need `Object<whatever>::RefCountT` when you do not know what `whatever` is. However, maybe thats not important

Comment: You could define a class ObjectBase, which defines the RefCount type and simply inherit from this one.

Comment: `using ArbitraryType = int; using Object<ArbitraryType>::RefCountT;` Or, just explain in a comment. I would find this one of the least confusing things in most C++ code :D

Comment: @tenfour the confusing thing about it is that you cannot be sure if `Object<ArbitraryType>::RefCountT` is the same as `Object<SomeOtherType>`. If it isnt you might run into problems, and if it is the same for all instantiation, why make it a member of the template in the first place

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Object` is just a template, but you need to instantiate it to access its member alias. I see several options:

A) Don't make `RefCountT` a member of `Object`.

B) Provide a default parameter so you need not explicitly pick a type to access the alias:

```
template <typename T = void>
struct Object {
    using RefCountT = unsigned short; // This is independent of T
};
```

then

```
Object<>::RefCount x;
```

C) Use a common base class for all instantiations:

```
struct ObjectBase {
    using RefCountT = unsigned short;
};

template <typename T>
struct Object : ObjectBase {
    using ObjectBase::RefCountT;
};
```

then

```
ObjectBase::RefCountT x;
```

---

In general it can be benefical to have anything that does not depend on the template parameter `T` not inside the template. Note that for example

```
template <>
struct Object<int> : ObjectBase {};
```

Is a specialization that has nothing in common with the general declaration of `Object` (ie no member alias). You would have to repeat everything in the specialization, unless you move it to the `ObjectBase`. Hence I would suggest A) or C).